# Sorting MAC address in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dict of mac addresses ,I want to sort them , I have tried the following code

```
a = a=[{"from":"00:25:B5:11:C1:00"},{"from":"00:25:B5:00:0A:08"},{"from":"00:25:B5:00:0B:08"},{"from":"00:25:B5:99:00:00"},{"from":"00:25:B5:99:00:00"},{"from":"00:25:B5:12:34:00"}]

b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x['from'].split(':')])
print(b)
```

but it gives the following error

```
invalid literal for int() with base10:B5
```

Not sure how to proceed.
Any help is appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your dictionary `a` contains the same key over and over again. This has no effect, and the dictionary will just contain one key-value pair. Is that a typo?

Comment: sorry my bad that was a typo

Comment: And what don't you understand about the error message? How would you translate `'B5'` to an `int`? Are these supposed to be `hex` values?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the string `B5` or `C1` will be converted to an integer?

Comment: you are trying to do `int('B5')` do you think this will work?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
a = a=[{"from":"00:25:B5:11:C1:00"},{"from":"00:25:B5:00:0A:08"},{"from":"00:25:B5:00:0B:08"},{"from":"00:25:B5:99:00:00"},{"from":"00:25:B5:99:00:00"},{"from":"00:25:B5:12:34:00"}]

b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: [y for y in x['from'].split(':')])
print(b)
```

you will get result like this

```
[{'from': '00:25:B5:00:0A:08'}, {'from': '00:25:B5:00:0B:08'}, {'from': '00:25:B5:11:C1:00'}, {'from': '00:25:B5:12:34:00'}, {'from': '00:25:B5:99:00:00'}, {'from': '00:25:B5:99:00:00'}]
```

Comment: Just `sorted(a, key=lambda i:i["from"])` will have the same effect